# jQuery script not working inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I wanted to execute script inside iframe tag but it does not worked for me, tried all kind of possible ways but still facing the same problem.

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/p4vzxdLc/) to jsFiddle

The content inside iframe is injected using script, style works perfect but my jQuery script is not working :( i don't know why...

can anyone solve my problem ??

Thanks.

code :

```js
 var htmlcontent = '<button id="btn">click me</button>';
 var previewFrame2 = document.getElementById('preview');
 var preview2 =  previewFrame2.contentDocument ||  previewFrame2.contentWindow.document;
 preview2.open();
 preview2.write(htmlcontent);
 preview2.close();

    var $head = $("#preview").contents().find("head");                
    $head.html("<style> button { padding:10px; border:0px; background:green } </style>");
    
    var $body = $("#preview").contents().find("body");
    $body.append("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'><\/script><script type='text/javascript' > jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('#btn').click(function() { alert('iam clicked') }); }); <\/script>");
```

```html
    <iframe id="preview" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536947/using-jquery-inside-iframe-not-working

Comment: Yeah, i have gone through this question but my script is inside the iframe where as the question you linked has script outside the iframe.

Comment: You can't use jQuery to append a script tag to load jQuery.  You need jQuery loaded FIRST, or else you need to use vanilla javascript to inject the script tag.